# cursor blinking automatically in jtable without mouse clicking

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have problem with cursor in `JTable`.
I've tried to find answer in the forum but can't find the answer I expected.
Here is my runnable Java:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Fpos extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Fpos frame = new Fpos();
                                    frame.setVisible(true);
                                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  //make frame center of screen                   
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                });
        }


        public Fpos() {
                //create Jpanel
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setBounds(10, 10, 1300, 700);
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(contentPane);
                contentPane.setLayout(null);
                //create label TOTAL
                JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("TOTAL : Rp.");
                lblTotal.setFont(new Font("Wide Latin", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                lblTotal.setBounds(33, 25, 312, 31);
                contentPane.add(lblTotal);
                //create label Total Amount
                JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("123,456,789");
                lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Wide Latin", Font.PLAIN, 60));
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(571, 6, 659, 61);
                contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
                //create jtable in scrollpane
                 JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());                 
                 JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table);
                 sp.setBounds(20,76,1240,572);
                 contentPane.add(sp);            
        }

    //tablemodel
    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
            private String[] columnNames = {"PLU", "NAME", "UOM", "QTY", "PRICE","AMOUNT"};
            private Object[][] data = {{"", "", "", new Double(0), new Integer(0), new Integer(0)}};    
            public int getColumnCount() {return columnNames.length;}
            public int getRowCount() {return data.length;}
//          public String getColumnName(int col) {return columnNames[col];}
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {return data[row][col];}
            //auto formating table: string=left alignment, numeric=right alignment, checkbox=check box not true/false
            public Class getColumnClass(int c) {return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();}
            //make table editable only for just first column        
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {if (col == 0) {return true;} else{return false;}}
            //make table can change value         
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                    data[row][col] = value;
                    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            }
    }

}
```

The output is just fine but the table is not ready to be input.
I have to double click column PLU first row to be ready for input.
What I want is as soon as I run it, cursor is blinking at column PLU first row, ready for input without double clicking it.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [`JTable#editCellAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editCellAt-int-int-)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, i've found the solution. I've posted new question  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447780/key-binding-in-jtable-editor. its keybinding bound to the table editor not the table. Hoping you can help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics would be:

```
table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);

if (table.editCellAt(0, 0))
{
    Component editor = table.getEditorComponent();
    editor.requestFocusInWindow();
    //((JTextComponent)editor).selectAll();
}
```

The `changeSelection(...)` is like clicking on the row (so the entire row gets highlighted), then the `editCellAt(...)` places the cell in edit mode.

Then you need to places focus on the editor and optionally select all the text so it can be replaced as you type.

Edit:

> The cursor is still not blinking

Wrap the code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to make sure the code is executed after the frame is visible:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        table.changeSelection(0, 1, false, false);

        if (table.editCellAt(0, 1))
        {
            Component editor = table.getEditorComponent();
            editor.requestFocusInWindow();
            //((JTextComponent)editor).selectAll();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Camickr for your quick reply. I've tried your solution n its ready for input (without double click) now as soon as I run it. Tho cursor is still not blinking on row 0 col 0 but I think its ok for now. My goal is developing a new software like POS software that cashier uses in supermarket, their table is always ready for input with cursor blinking on col 0. Is it possible for that Mr/Mrs/Ms Camickr?

Comment: @Hendra, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I'm sorry Camickr, this is my first time posting a question. I can't find the checkmark in this page. May I ask where is the checkmark?

Comment: I think I found where the checkmark is. There is up button on your answer (comment=the answer is useful). I've clicked it 4 times. It says thanks for the feedback etc. I hope it works

Comment: Not up bottom but check button under down bottom. I've checked your answer. Thanks Camickr.

Comment: Hi Camickr, I've posted new question hoping you can help too, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447780/key-binding-in-jtable-editor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that added code make cursor blinking on selected cell n making it ready for input.

Thank you very much Camickr.

I put the runnable code below just in case someone may happen to meet same case.

```
import java.awt.Component;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            try {
                                test frame = new test();
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      //make frame center of screen                   
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            });
    }


    public test() {
            //create Jpanel
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(10, 10, 1300, 700);
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            //create label TOTAL
            JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("TOTAL : Rp.");
            lblTotal.setFont(new Font("Wide Latin", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            lblTotal.setBounds(33, 25, 312, 31);
            contentPane.add(lblTotal);
            //create label Total Amount
            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("123,456,789");
            lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Wide Latin", Font.PLAIN, 60));
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(571, 6, 659, 61);
            contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
            //create jtable in scrollpane
             JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());                 
             JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table);
             sp.setBounds(20,76,1240,572);
             contentPane.add(sp);
            //make cursor blinking on selected cell
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                          table.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
                          if (table.editCellAt(0, 0)){
                              Component editor = table.getEditorComponent();
                              editor.requestFocusInWindow();
                              //((JTextComponent)editor).selectAll();
                          }
                    }
            });

    }

//tablemodel
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"PLU", "NAME", "UOM", "QTY", "PRICE","AMOUNT"};
        private Object[][] data = {{"", "", "", new Double(0), new Integer(0), new Integer(0)}};    
        public int getColumnCount() {return columnNames.length;}
        public int getRowCount() {return data.length;}
//          public String getColumnName(int col) {return columnNames[col];}
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {return data[row][col];}
        //auto formating table: string=left alignment, numeric=right alignment, checkbox=check box not true/false
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();}
        //make table editable only for just first column        
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {if (col == 0) {return true;} else{return false;}}
        //make table can change value         
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                data[row][col] = value;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
}
```

}